# Ubuntu 18.04 can't open software & update

Tags: python, ubuntu, apt

After I install and replace Python 3.6 to Python 3.7, I can't open my software & update, also upgrade software too, I tried open terminal and using sudo apt update, but doesn't work and pop up an error like this:

```
appstreamcli: error while loading shared libraries: libxapian.so.22: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Reading package lists... Done
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'if /usr/bin/test -w /var/cache/app-info -a -e /usr/bin/appstreamcli; then appstreamcli refresh-cache > /dev/null; fi'
E: Sub-process returned an error code
```

How to solve it?

Comment: Maybe you will find your answer there : https://askubuntu.com/questions/894519/ubuntu-16-04-appstreamcli-error-while-get-update

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution helped me here to upgrade to Ubuntu 19

Step 1. Download the installer for disco: archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/disco-updates/main/dist-upgrader-all/current/disco.tar.gz
Step 2. Extract the tar, tar -xvf disco.tar.gz

Step 3. Change to the directory where it was extracted to (go to the extracted folder and right click and open command there). Run command: sudo ./disco

Step 4. Follow the usual installer.

(Link org: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1209016/cannot-i-upgrade-18-10-to-19-10-without-a-total-uninstall-a-new-install)

Comment: I forgot how I actually solve this problem, but I guess I'm just reinstalling my Ubuntu. Thank you anyway.